# og:image not working for wordpress pages

Tags: facebook, wordpress, thumbnails

I have no clue why the image is not featuring , 
Here is a link, but the same is happening with other wordpress pages..

http://www.alcireland.ie/find-a-consultant/

```
<meta content="http://www.alcireland.ie/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/home-map.jpg" property="og:image">
```

http://www.alcireland.ie/external-links/

```
<meta content="http://www.alcireland.ie/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/logo.png" property="og:image">
```

Are there certain criteria to be met that Im not meeting? I dont necessarily want the image to actually be on the page, I just want it to be included when the page is shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: First the image is too small. Second, Facebook caches the pages so it will need scraping again before any changes are reflected on facebook.

I forced a new scrape using their tool which you should use for checking OG properties:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Before I forced a rescrape it was reporting that it couldn't detect the og:image property, now it is reporting that the image declared is too small:

"Provided og:image could not be downloaded or is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook. Image 'http://www.alcireland.ie/wp-content/themes/surgetheme/images/logo.png' will be used instead."